# FFT on SDR FM Radio Signal

Tags: fft, software-defined-radio, frequency-modulation

I recorded a simple FM signal using my SDR (centered at 100.3e6 hz and sample rate of 2.048e6 per second). Without any transformation, I ran an FFT on the signal and it showed a signal with some width to it at 0 hz (not a line that would indicate a bias but signal centered around 0).  I would have assumed the FFT would show a signal with frequency of 100.3e6 hz because that’s the carrier. But I’m learning that SDR downconverts the signal from carrier to baseband.

My question is, what exactly is baseband and this downconversion process. I haven’t found a coherent explanation. When I visualize the FM signal I’d expect to see a radio wave at 100.3e6 hz with changes in frequency as it modulates the sound. But this indicates that it’s at 0hz? What does that even mean? Could anyone help me understand this better.

Comment: Your question is far too broad and is covered in hundreds of textbooks. I'd suggest starting with this free one: https://pysdr.org/